# Set orientation on UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I am trying to set the orientation for a `UIViewController` and disallow all orientation changes on that `UIViewController`. It is important to note that the app allows all orientations, but on this one view controller I want to allow only portrait orientation.

I am working on iOS 8, the app works with iOS 6 and up. The described behavior is happening in iOS 7 and 8. I cannot test it in iOS 6 so I am not sure if it occurs in iOS 6.

I have the following methods implemented:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO; // I've also tried returning YES - no success
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // I've also tried UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait - no success
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // Never called
}
```

I have been able to set the orientation for a view controller that is presented modally, but I am not presenting the view controller modally for this project. Can this even be done?

How do I specify the orientation for one UIViewController, without effecting the orientation of other UIViewControllers? Can this even be done?

Comment: I am seeing this behaviour as well (supportedInterfaceOrientations not called) but in my case the objective is the reverse (view controller should support rotate while others don't). Fortunately I can switch what gets returned in supportedInterfaceOrientations to force the initial orientation during presentation, but that won't help you :(

Comment: Is the incorrect behavior happening in iOS 6, 7, and 8? Or just 8?

Comment: @Riley I know for sure it is happening in iOS 7 & 8. I cannot test iOS 6, so I just assume it occurs in iOS 6 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, you need to use a custom subclass of `UINavigationController` and add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
{
    BOOL shouldAutorotate;
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)])
    {
        shouldAutorotate = [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
     }
     else {
        shouldAutorotate = [super shouldAutorotate];
      }
      return shouldAutorotate;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger supportedOrientations;
    if ([[self topViewController] respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        supportedOrientations = [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    else {
        supportedOrientations = [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return supportedOrientations;
}
```

in your navigation controller. The methods in your view controller are just fine, so leave them as they are. That works in iOS 7-8 (haven't tested in iOS6)

Comment: I used a solution very similar to this. I just created a UIForcedOrientationNavigationController and wrap my view controller with that. Thanks!